# Is there a way to import module as a new instance in boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

if we use boost-python in c++ to import a python module as `boost::python::import("module_name");` we get a refence to the instance of the module. Calling this repeatedly will always return the same instance of the module. This is fine as this is how python import works.

But if we want a new instance of the module while old instance is being used can we do that ? we can do it via python by deleting the module from `sys.modules` but is that the only way ? Does boost provide an interface for this ?

Comment: By new instance you mean you want a python's `reload` behavior ?

Comment: I think in my case reload will work. If I have reference to old classes in the module those reference will continue to be there while I reload and create new class objects.